# IP address never found in dhcp leases file - minishift

Tags: minishift

I am trying to start minishift in MacOS Big Sur but getting the error like below:

```
FAIL E0802 17:24:16.423337    1544 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: IP address never found in dhcp leases file Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 6:c0:c4:12:f0:d6
```

[image]

Trying to run the same in Ubuntu running inside Vmware. I Have enabled Virtualization in VM too.
Got below error:

```
Starting Minishift VM ..... FAIL E0802 06:20:29.211988    3438 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message='internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2021-08-02T13:20:26.719953Z qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x48d to 0x5600000016
qemu-system-x86_64: /build/qemu-rbeYHu/qemu-4.2/target/i386/kvm.c:2691: kvm_buf_set_msrs: Assertion `ret == cpu->kvm_msr_buf->nmsrs' failed.'). Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message='internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2021-08-02T13:20:26.719953Z qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x48d to 0x5600000016
qemu-system-x86_64: /build/qemu-rbeYHu/qemu-4.2/target/i386/kvm.c:2691: kvm_buf_set_msrs: Assertion `ret == cpu->kvm_msr_buf->nmsrs' failed.')
```

Ubuntu VM has 12 GB of RAM.

Could somebody help me out to solve this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used virtual box as hypervisor : `minishift config set vm-driver virtualbox`